# display context menu for position "2" click in list view only android

Tags: android

I want to display context menu for list position clicked means only for 2 nd position clicked in list view so how to do it.

I had implemented the code for displaying context menu for each position clicked. So how to make it specific for any position in `ListView`.

my code for displaying context menu for each position in list view ..pls do required modification  on my code thanks...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenulist);

    // registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(
        this, R.layout.listitem,R.id.title, data
    );
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,
  View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Gallery");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Camera");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Cancel");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getTitle()=="Gallery"){
        function1(item.getItemId());
    } else if(item.getTitle()=="Camera"){
        function2(item.getItemId());
    } else return false;
    return true;
}

public void function1(int id){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Gallery function called",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
}

public void function2(int id){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Camera function  called",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I can see only onCreateOptionsMenu() method. In order to restrict the options menu as you wish, you have to add one more method to it.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);


   }
```

And now when you click on the listview get the position of the item that is being clciked and store it globally. Now change the above method like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

            if(list_item_position==2){
               return true;
     }
   else
     return false;
   }
```

Now your options menu will pop up only if the list item in second position is clicked.

Comment: dear andro selva i am not using onCreateOptionsMenu() ,i am using onCreateContextMenu so pls. give me suggetion for onCreateContextMenu() .thanks for responce...:)

Comment: Then change the method name to onPrepareContextMenu() instead of onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Comment: what is list_item_position in if(list_item_position==2) bcoz it is giving error on list_item_position.

Comment: how to get list_item_position on list position click?

Comment: i add ur method but it display context menu for each position clicked on list...how to restrict it for 2nd position click only

Comment: inside your listviewiemclick do this,
if(position==1){
        list_item_position=2;
       openContextMenu((View) menu);
       }

Comment: how to intialise "menu" in openContextMenu((View) menu); ? if i do ContextMenu menu="null" then givig null pointer exception

Comment: hello andro i think onListItemclick() run when i release the press from list position so it will not execute on long press on list position so code also run inside of it after releasing position click..so i think it is not possible?what u say?